# Maximum number of descendants in a B-tree

Tags: b-tree

If you know the order of a B-tree, how do you figure out the maximum number of descendants from a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of descendants is just the number of points in the node, since each pointer points to a descendant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the current depth below that page, then it's just arithmetic.

Comment: I'm still not getting it.  Can you or someone else elaborate with an example?

Comment: If you have one set of pages below the current page, the maximum number of descendants from that page is N squared, because there can be up to N descendants and each can contain up to N items. If you have another level below that ... work it out for yourself ...